# Как получить время выполнения теста?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, юнит-тесты, nunit

Всем привет, выполняю свои ui-тесты (C# + Selenium + NUnit).
Необходимо получить значение - Время выполнения теста.
Можно использовать различные таймеры, вызывать их в начале и конце теста, но наверняка есть готовое решение?
В Visual Studio, в Обозревателе тестов есть значение - Elapsed time, могу ли я получить его?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Запускать тесты из [консоли](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line). Парсить вывод.

Comment: Можно написать плагин к nunit, у того была информация по времени выполнения. Мб есть какой то аттрибут, который неплохо подойдет по жизненному циклу теста (и не придётся писать плагин), но я их так навскидку не помню.